# Дефолтное значение для material 2 datepicker

Tags: angular2, datepicker

Помогите пожалуйста установить дефолтное значение в datepicker ng material 2

в моём случае сам датапикер связан с моделью так:

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" [(ngModel)]="modelDateBegin">
  <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="picker"></button>
</md-input-container>
<md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
```

В компоненте устанавливается значение модели так:

```
export class DatepickerOverviewExample {
  private modelDateBegin = '02.07.2017';
}
```

В результате браузер показывает датепикер, в котором предустановлено значение: "07.02.2017". Это явно не то что было установлено в компоненте

Живой пример здесь: [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/kQO5CEdE0XPuuAdW3of5?p=preview)

PS:

При этом если на этой же странице использовать второй датепикер, то описанным выше способом значение в нём вообще не устанавливается

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, проблема в формате даты, `private modelDateBegin = '02.07.2017'` - в американском формате `(MM/dd/yyyy)`, где сначала идет месяц, а потом день, это 7 февраля а не 2 июля. Не установится значение, если число месяца больше 12, например `'15.07.2017'`.

Comment: А откуда такой формат "MM/dd/yyyy"? Это наугад пробовать нужно?

Comment: Скорее всего компонент имеет настройку формата. А по умолчанию стоит формат даты en-US, в котором дата записывается в таком виде: месяц/день/год.

Comment: [Здесь](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datepicker) есть описание компонента и там показано, как менять формат даты.